# Applications of position-space formula for a Feynman propagator?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, greens-functions, propagator

In QFT, it seems the [propagator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator) has a simple closed form in momentum space. The position space representation is more complicated, but [could be worse](https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.1261) -- basically it's a Bessel function (depending, of course, on what field one is talking about).

**Question:** What are some applications of knowing the precise analytic form of a Feynman propagator in position space? For instance, if numerical computations of the zeros of Bessel functions (in the context of propagators) have been used to make a physical prediction, I'd be interested to hear about that.

For example, for a 3+1-dimensional massive scalar field, the propagator in momentum space is

$$D(p) = \frac{1}{p^2 - m^2 \pm i \epsilon}$$

whereas in position space, according to the above-linked paper, it's

$$D(x) = \Theta(x^2) \frac{m}{8\pi\sqrt{x^2 - i\epsilon}}H^{(2)}_1(m \sqrt{x^2 - i\epsilon}) + \Theta(-x^2) \frac{m}{4\pi^2\sqrt{-x^2 + i\epsilon}}K_1(m\sqrt{-x^2 + i\epsilon})$$

where $\Theta$ is the Heaviside step function and $H^{(2)}_1$ and $K_1$ are certain Bessel functions.

The only use I happen to have seen made of the position-space representation is to verify that the propagator decays exponentially outside the light cone (for which you can make a crude estimate without knowing anything about Bessel functions).

Comment: In response to votes to close as "opinion-based", I've tried to remove any "opinion-y" language in the question.

Comment: Looking back, it still confuses me that this question was closed even after I fixed the superficial issues with phrasing. I think I can understand that a question of the form "Is X ever relevant to physics?" might be seen as problematic. But after rephrasing, I don't understand the issue. Does this site discourage questions of the form "what are some examples of X?" because they are a bit open-ended? Or is the distinction I'm making -- between the use of two mathematically equivalent representations of one object -- not considered to be something one can objectively make?

Comment: Or am I expected to have done a bit more legwork in looking for answers to my question before asking?

Comment: Section 4.5 of paper "Vacuum Noise and Stress Induced by Uniform Acceleration" by Takagi uses the massive position space propagator (the Wightman function) to calculate the rate of excitation of a two-level detector which uniformly accelerated through Minkowski space (this then tells you the Unruh temperature). This calculation requires your formula for the propagator (or more precisely, the Wightman function which is the same as your formula with the $i \epsilon$ in different places).

Comment: Questions with non-unique answers fit poorly to the SE Q&A format.

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanks for the explanation. Over at MathOverflow, we're more relaxed on this point. Even big list questions have a specific, cherished place in our culture, and focused small lists come up frequently. In Phsyics SE's [discussion on meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4561/good-list-bad-list) from years ago, there was some suggestion of allowing certain focused list-type questions, but maybe it fizzled out. The suggestion there seems to be that if I reword to ask "is there a unique application of the position-space formula..." it will be better?

Comment: In a [later discussion on meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8832/why-close-list-based-questions) knzhou also emphasizes that the acceptability of a question in this regard is very sensitive to phrasing.

Comment: @Qmechanic Sorry to bother you again. You put in the effort to add tags and explain the new closure reason to me, which I really appreciate. I take this to indicate that you don't see the question as worthless -- maybe you think it's salvageable. But I'm not sure how. The edit I suggested in my last comment feels like a _worse_ question to me, so I would only try it if I was pretty sure it was the only way to make the question acceptable.

Comment: It seems off-topic, but I don't want to close it unilaterally. Let's see what the Phys.SE community thinks.

Comment: Thanks for the response again. When you say "off-topic", do you mean that this isn't really a physics question at all? When you say "see what the community thinks", do you mean I should make the edit I suggested and submit it for reopening again? Or should it be raised on meta?

Comment: Oh I see. I needed to refresh my browser to see that the question was reopened again. Thank you @Qmechanic !

Comment: @QuantumEyedea Thanks for your comment -- this is just the sort of thing I was looking for! I just thought I'd point out that the question has reopened, so you might want to turn your comment into an answer (if you don't, I'll probably make it a CW answer).

Answer (score 3):

A mathematical application (see Section 6.5 of [1]): The position-space Feynman propagator is analytic away from the light cone. In particular, there is no domain in $\mathbb{R}^4$ where it vanishes identically. This is not so easy to show without an explicit analytic expression.

[1] G.B.Folland, Quantum field theory. A tourist guide for mathematicians, Math.Surveys & Monographs 149, AMS, 2008.

Comment: Interesting -- Folland does discuss deducing smoothness via abstract considerations which I think extend beyond the real scalar field. He doesn't mention analyticity explicitly -- that's a nice observation by you to get to the "full support" conclusion! I don't know enough PDEs, but I have to imagine there are arguments for analyticity which are abstract enough to apply to lots of different fields at once (since a drawback of relying on the formula for this is that you have to derive a new formula for each type of field). But as you say, this would require some fancy math!

Comment: @tcamps Surely there should be general tools guaranteeing the analyticity. Explicit analytic expression just simplifies the proof in some particular cases.

Answer (score 2):

Section 4.5 of paper ["Vacuum Noise and Stress Induced by Uniform Acceleration"](https://academic.oup.com/ptps/article/doi/10.1143/PTP.88.1/1938595?login=true) by Takagi uses the massive position space propagator (the Wightman function) to calculate the rate of excitation of a two-level detector which uniformly accelerated through Minkowski space (this then tells you the Unruh temperature). This calculation requires your formula for the propagator (or more precisely, the Wightman function which is the same as your formula with the  in different places):
$$
\langle 0 | \phi(x)\phi(y) | 0 \rangle = \frac{m}{4 \pi^2 \sqrt{ - (\Delta t 
 - i \epsilon)^2 + |\Delta \mathbf{x}|^2 }} K_1\left( m \sqrt{ - (\Delta t 
 - i \epsilon)^2 + |\Delta \mathbf{x}|^2 } \right)
$$
where $\Delta t := x^0 - y^0 $ and $\Delta \mathbf{x} := \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}$. Note this is not time-ordered, unlike the Feynman propagator.